# Could not load file or assembly in SSRS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssrs

I have **Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise** installed on Windows 10. In a separate from SSRS solution I created a Visual Basic project named "CustomFunctionsVB". In this project I created a class library "DateFunctions.vb" that has one function. I built the project and copied the **.dll** to

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies**.

In the SSRS project I opened the report (.rdl) and went to the Report Properties to add a reference to the library I copied to the path mentioned above.

.dll location

[image: .dll location]

SSRS Report Properties:

[image: SSRS Report Properties]

Now if I try to preview the report I am getting this error:

Error
[image: error]

Where should I copy the .dll, so it's available for VS 2017 in the debugging mode?

Also, what should be the location on the **server** for a deployed report to be able to use that .dll?

Thanks!